# Reading values from console overwrites a struct

Tags: c, string, user-input

I made a small program where I have a struct and filling its parameter based on value from console.

```
#define M 3
struct data {
    char* info;
    int key;
};

void initHash(data* d) {
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<M; i++) {
        d[i].info = " ";
        d[i].key = -1;
    }
}


void printList(data* d) {
    int i;
    for(i=0; i< M; i++) {
        if(strcmp(d[i].info, " ")) {
            printf(" %d %d %s \n", i, d[i].key, d[i].info);
        }
    }
}

int linearProbing() {
    struct data d[M];
    int hashval;
    char* info;
    char str[25];


    initHash(d);
    scanf("%s",&str);
    while(strcmp(str, "end") != 0) {
    d[id].info = str;
    **printf("before reading \n");
    printList(d);
    id++;
    scanf("%s",&str);
    printf("after reading \n");
    printList(d);
    printf("next iter \n");**
    }
    printList(d);
    return true;
}
```

My issue is in the highlighted lines the first print function prints correct value but after getting input , the data.info param changes to the new input value for all the M members of struct array. Can someone explain why it might be so?

Sample output:

```
statue
before reading 
 0 -1 statue 
tornado
after reading 
 0 -1 tornado 
next iter 
before reading 
 0 -1 tornado 
 1 -1 tornado 
clown
after reading 
 0 -1 clown 
 1 -1 clown 
next iter 
before reading 
 0 -1 clown 
 1 -1 clown 
 2 -1 clown
```

Comment: Are you even able to compile this? I can see a lot of bugs.

Comment: Looks like C++ to me?

Comment: Yup, should be tagged under C++

Comment: What? Where do you see any c++? Am I blind? 'cause I don't see any c++ line in there, however I do recognize plenty c-style stuff. `c++` would be miss-tagging it IMO.

Comment: Variable declaration inside `for` loop isn't allowed in C. Also, variables are declared in the code using `data` instead of `struct data`.

Comment: Sounds like C compiled on a C++ compiler (because that's clearly C style).

Comment: My mistake, I might have compiled using C++ compiler in eclipse. However, I forgot to miss on those two points. But still haven't used any core C++ stuff in it. I'll edit the code to make it strictly C.

Comment: @Kunal you can declare variables like that `c` (at least on modern version) by using `typedef` when declaring struct. I think calling code `c++`-like only cause of a in-loop variable declaration with all those `printf`s `scanf`s and OOP implementated using `struct` + functions operating on pointers to those structs is not a bold statement, but a mistake. But I give you that `c` compiler would fail to compile it and `c++` would!

Comment: `typedef` was my first thought too, but that was missing in the code.

Comment: Please get a real C compiler like GCC, compile the code, fix all errors then repost. For example `gcc -std=c99 -pedantic-errors -Wall`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're not copying the input strings to each `d[id].info` member - you're setting those pointers to the *same* character buffer (`str`), which you're using and overwriting again and again.

That is, `d[0].info`, `d[1].info`, etc. all point to the same memory.

You likely want to say:

```
d[id].info = strdup(str);
```

to point to a new copy of the string each time.

Comment: ... and a subsequent loop to `free()` that data before function exit.

Answer (score 2):

You are making the `info` variable point to a string literal. In order to store a string, you should first allocate sufficient storage like:

`info = (char *) malloc(string size * sizeof(char))`

and then copy your string using `strcpy`

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always `1`. Do not cast the result of `malloc/calloc/realloc` as it is not necessary nor recommended: http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/694576.

Comment: @alk Thanks. Didn't know about the casting stuff.